# How to rotate image more than once in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, rotation

I have opened an image with an open file dialog.

`image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofd.FileName));`

Then I want to rotate it as many times as I like and finally save the modified image. The problem is that with code from MSDN:

```
var biOriginal = (BitmapImage)image.Source;
var biRotated = new BitmapImage();
biRotated.BeginInit();
biRotated.UriSource = biOriginal.UriSource;
biRotated.Rotation = Rotation.Rotate90;
biRotated.EndInit();
image.Source = biRotated;
```

I can rotate the image, but only one time and I'm not able to save the rotated image.

Comment: [Saving a BitmapImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161359/save-bitmapimage-to-file) and [rotate by angle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309086/rotate-a-bitmapimage) (or repeat your code in a loop if you want more than one rotation)

Comment: cannot rotate like that due to exception Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TransformedBitmap'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you just need to rotate the image. You can do this by applying a layout transform to `Image` element in XAML and changing it's (transform's) angle value on button click. Also it looks like you are not following MVVM. If you do, see how simple it is:

**View**

```
<Image Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="125">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding RotateAngle}" />
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
<Button Content="Rotate" Command="{Binding RotateCommand}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ICommand rotateCommand;
    private double rotateAngle;

    public ICommand RotateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if(rotateCommand == null)
            {
                rotateCommand = new RelayCommand(() => {
                    RotateAngle += 90;
                });
            }

            return rotateCommand;
        }
    }

    public double RotateAngle
    {
        get
        {
            return rotateAngle;
        }

        private set
        {
            if(value != rotateAngle)
            {
                rotateAngle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("RotateAngle");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View Code-behind**

```
ViewModel vm;

public View()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

[image]

I am assuming you are not absolute beginner in MVVM/WPF and omitted definitions of BaseViewModel (implements INotifyPropertyChanged) and RelayCommand (implements ICommand) as I didn't want to make answer too lengthy. If you are having trouble with these, let me know, I will include them here.

Answer (score -1):

The following code seems to work:

```
            BitmapImage newImage = new BitmapImage();
        newImage.BeginInit();
        newImage.UriSource = MyImage.UriSource;
        newImage.Rotation = Rotation.Rotate90;
        newImage.EndInit();
        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        string ImageName = Path.Combine( Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures), (Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg"));
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(newImage));

        using (var filestream = new FileStream(ImageName, FileMode.Create))
            encoder.Save(filestream);
        MyImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ImageName));
```

It creates a new image every time you rotate it of course, if you want to rotate more than once the image and save it only once I haven't found a simple way to make multiple rotations without saving the rotated image.